# Comparing reply of a webclient which is in xml format with the saved text files in Selenium

Tags: java, xml, selenium

I am very new to Selenium and trying to get the reply of my webclient which will will displayed in XML format after clicking on submit button.All replies will be shown in Webpage. Moreover i know the expected reply. I am not able to find a suitable method to get the XML reply. I tried using selenium.getHtmlSource() but it is giving me the result of the parent Page. Could anyone suggest a suitable way of solving my issue? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: So to clarify - you click a submit button which opens a new webpage and on that page is the `xml` data you want to parse?

Comment: are you sure that Selenium is the best tool for this? It is not intended for this. Check [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource%28%29)

Comment: @MarkRowlands: Exactly

Comment: @user1134289 Then as mentioned above, Selenium probably isn't the best tool for you to use. I guess you could still find the `<body>` and `getText()` (because I'm assuming the `xml` will be in the `<body>` element) but then you'd have to convert from a string.

Comment: i am just in the final stage.. if it can be done anyway i can complete my project.. i can take it as a string as well... no problem for that too whether string or anything.. just give a way out masters

Comment: even if i can save the current loaded file.. that will also do if no other means :)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. What i was in need is to somehow save the XML which i was getting as a reply in webpage. SO i found one workaround for me. As the reply page had nothing except the XML so i used FirefoxDriver.get("myURL"). myURL i was taking using the function selenium.getLocation(). Then simply using driver.getPageSource() and saving the string into a file made my work easy. I know this is just a workaround but it is useful for me.

Thanks guys whoever tried to find answer for me.